# For some reason my routing in react doesn't work using react-router

Tags: reactjs

I have tried implementing react-router routing library to my react application... 
here is my main component code. When i have just the '`<Route path="/" component={App} />`' without '`<Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />`' The App component gets rendered but when I have both, nothing gets rendered. was wondering if i was doing something wrong.

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

import LandingPage from './landingpage';
import Admin from './admin';

injectTapEventPlugin();

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <LandingPage />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('spot')
);
```

heres my admin component

```
import React from 'react';

class Admin extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>Holla</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Admin;
```

and my webpack configuration

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/app.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    hot: true,
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried adding Switch to render your routes exclusively?

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

You may also need to add the exact attribute to your home path, like this:

<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
  </Router>

Comment: Thank you.. the exact was a more subtle answer

Answer (score 2):

React-Router 4 accepts only one child. Try:

```
   <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
```

or

```
   <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
    </div>
  </Router>,
```

Comment: don't forget to import switch from react-router-dom! but alex is right.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the MUI theme provider not being available for your admin component and that the router only accepts one child. Try placing your muithemeprovider here instead:

```
ReactDOM.render(

  <Router>
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
  </MuiThemeProvider>      
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('spot')
);
```

So that it's available for all your components and not just App